# NoBatteryNoProblem.kext not working on 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: macos, kernel-extensions

I have a Macbook Pro Early 2011 (i7 Sandy Bridge) with a dead battery.
I tried using `NoBatteryNoProblem.kext` to lift it out of its glacial BD PROCHOT state, but it isn't working.

I successfully executed `make` and `make load`, and Terminal reports

```
\tmp\NoBatteryNoProblem.kext successfully loaded (or already loaded)
```

But the processor never speeds up. `Kernel_task` continues to hog the CPU time. What can I do?